# Using Sublime Text CLI (subl) "command" argument

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to use Sublime Text in a script to save a text file with UTF-8 encoding, `subl --help` shows :

> --command : Run the given command

I found a list of [commands](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands) and tried typing

```
subl --command "saveAs UTF-8" file.txt
```

with no success.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: The documentation says the parameters may be enclosed in quotes, not the commands. `subl --command saveAs UTF-8 "file.txt"` should work. But this saves the current buffer to a file. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: For the record, I didn't manage to make this approach (subl) work.  I now use **[uchardet](https://code.google.com/p/uchardet/)** in combination with **iconv** to achieve the utf-8 conversion.